# Finding a list item within a list item

Tags: c#

I'm a bit confused on how this works.

```
class TestClass
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public List<Stuff> StuffList {get; set;}
}
class Stuff
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

So each `TestClass` has a list of `Stuff` in them.
What I want to do is find a `TestClass` that contains any `Stuff` with an `ID` of `0`

```
List<TestClass> TestList = RetrieveAllTestLists();
//Pseudocode:
//
// Find all TestClass in TestList that contain a Stuff with ID == 0;
```

I've tried this but it didn't work:

```
List<TestClass> TestList = RetrieveAllTestLists().Where(x=> x.StuffList.Where(y=> y.ID == 0)).ToList();
```

Can anyone explain to me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Any`:

```
List<TestClass> TestList = RetrieveAllTestLists().
                           Where(x => x.StuffList.Any(y=> y.ID == 0)).ToList();
```

Basicaly `Where` will select all rows which satisfies condition (those returning `true`), but in this place you have another `Where`. `Any` will return `true` if there were any row fulfilling given condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<TestClass> TestList = RetrieveAllTestLists().Where(x=> x.StuffList.Any(y=> y.ID == 0)).ToList();
```

Any() means that at least for one element or the IEnumerable, the predicate given in parameter returns true